# Getting datagridview selected row column values to Combobox

Tags: c#

need help on getting the values from `datagridview` to `combobox`, I am having a `datagridview` getting data's from SQL which counts  5 columns and number of rows retrieved from SQL, I am having 4 textboxes & 2 comboboxes.

I have written code for `textbox` & `combobox` like below.

```
               int i;
               i = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;

             textBox4.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
             textBox3.Text= dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

            comboBox1.SelectedValue = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();

            textBox5.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            comboBox2.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString());
```

I'm getting textbox values perfectly but want the `datagridview` selected row's column values to the combobox.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use SelectedIndex, use SelectedValue.

Try this:

```
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "MyFieldText";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "MyFieldId";
var myObject = (MyObject)dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;
comboBox1.SelectedValue = myObject.Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add these strings to comboBox you should not use SelectedIndex property.

If I understand your intention correctly here is what I think you are looking for:

```
comboBox2.Items.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: well what i meant to say is i have wrote the above code for celldouble click event. and have full row select property, so whenever i double click on the row , the data in the fields should appear back in textbox as well as combo box

Comment: @Rahul <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="DataGridCell_MouseDoubleClick"/> inside your datagrid, then in definition of DataGridCell_MouseDoubleClick put code from your question and change selectedindex lines to what I provided in my answer.